# My hot water won't turn on unless the central heating is on as well, why?

Tags: hot-water, central-heating

I've looked at a few related questions, and I can't see a similar question being posed.

Our hot water taps only work (i.e. produce hot water) if the central heating has been on, which we tend not to do in hot weather. Subsequently, we don't have hot water when the weather is hot! Instead what comes out is luke-warm at best.

If I turn the central heating on for a few hours, I get hot water for ~12 hours before it runs out.

Downstairs we have this thermostat (Potterton PR2 thermostat):

[image: Potterton PR2 thermostat]
<sub>Image sourced from google</sub>

And upstairs attached to the hot water tank, this thermostat (Potterton PTT2 thermostat):

[image: Potterton PTT2 thermostat]
<sub>Image sourced from google</sub>

In the kitchen we have a combi-boiler, with a 'Potterton Ep2000 Heating And Hot Water Programmer' below it, that I'm guessing are connected?

[image: Potterton Ep2000 Heating And Hot Water Programmer]
<sub>Image sourced from google</sub>

There's definitely a 3-way valve in the airing cupboard that controls the state of the hot water (e.g. CH, CH&HW, HW etc).

What could be causing this?

Comment: I've been meaning to post this for a long time, but I keep forgetting to make time at home. When I'm at home I can fill in more details as required (photos of thermostats, makes of boilers etc)

Comment: How is the water heated?  Separate from central heating or combined?  What is central heating type.  It sounds like hot water uses heat from central heating instead of having a separate heater or uses central heat when on, to reduce fuel for water heater and water heater has failed.

Comment: You say hot water taps only work with central heat on.  You mean only cold water comes out or no water comes out?

Comment: @crip659 I mean only luke-warm water comes out. We have a combi-boiler in the kitchen, with a 'programmer' below it. And we have a hot water tank above it in an airing cupboard

Comment: Does hot water have a way to heat water(gas/electric) or just a holding tank?  I am guessing heater on hot water has failed, but combi-boiler is heating/supplying water in tank.

Comment: @crip659 I don't know how to find that out... My understanding (from similar set ups) was that all the hot water in the system (taps and radiators) was shared. IT went from the boiler to the holding tank, and then onto either the taps or the radiators.

Comment: A plain holding tank will only have water pipes to/from it.  A heating tank will have wires/gas lines also.

Comment: Has this always worked like this, if not you probably have a failed valve or thermostat. If it always worked like this it may not have been properly installed at the start.

Comment: @Gil we've only lived in that house for 2 years, but it was built in the 90s (as far as I'm aware). We've had the issue for as long as we've been there though.

Answer (score -1):

That places the equipment at about 30 years old. It is probably at the end of its life. You could replace the systems or repair them. If it were me I would replace both the heating system and the hot water system and separate them as two independent systems. I have a system similar to yours in a small way. I have instant hot that works with a circulation pump. I put heat fins in the basement and in the winter I return the water to the tank via the fin tubs, in the summer valves bypass that. The lost heat goes through the ceiling (floor of main home) and gets used twice. The basement stays comfortable, that is my play area. When it gets to about -10F out we start to run short on hot water so I simply set the basement a little cooler and all is well. I believe you are living in a warmer area, You could use the same boiler for both as you now are. Once you get a quote get one for a proper repair on your existing system that will help you make an informed choice.

Comment: It sounds more like the op is not aware how to change the system over more than a failure.

Comment: When they are inspecting for a quote they hopefully will find it and show her how to switch the system over. Maybe she should ask a HVAC tech to come out and check the system and explain it to the op. Good Catch!

Comment: @edbeal what am I missing in terms of what can be changed over? I'm expecting year round hot water in my hot tap, but I'm only getting it when the central heating is on.

Comment: @Pureferret, I agree you expect hot water but the controller may need to be configured to change modes, we don’t know your system. In some cases it may save you in power to call the company in that installed it and have them show you how to change seasons. But ask for a tech that installs that type/ brand.

Comment: @edbeal but the controller does change modes. Changing mode doesn't seem to do anything though. To me that sounds more like it's broken...?

Comment: @pureferret are the modes properly programmed? I have seen fancy controller systems that were installed in a default setup the owner was bragging on one as it was over 1k and all it could do but it had never been optimized so it was a very fancy toggle switch until properly set up.

Comment: @edbeal I'm not using the programming...? The hot water setting is 'on' 24/7 but I only get it when the central heating is also on.